# Can't check profile model in django python shell

Tags: python, django, django-shell

I am trying to run the django shell to understand what is happening to the photos when I upload them.

However when I try to filter for particular users

```
python manage.py shell
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.filter(username='name').first()
```

I get the following error message:

> AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'classroom.User'

I am guessing this has something to do with this in settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'classroom.User'
```

What should I be typing to get to look at the profile model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, it does have something to do with:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'classroom.User'
```

Since you specified what I would assume is a `Custom User Model`. In which case you woud have to use the method `get_user_model()` as specified in Django's [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) to reference your new `User` model.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

Comment: Thanks, getting the error message:

    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model()
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Emm take off the () in your import.

Comment: thanks, getting this error now: ImportError: cannot import name 'get_user_model' from 'django.contrib.auth.models' (C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dj
ango\contrib\auth\models.py)

Comment: As you can see above you should import from django.contrib.auth